# Giving error when using Provider state management in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I am trying to increase counter when app call init and using provider to change the state of counter but getting this error i don't understand why i have made the listen to false but no solved kindly help

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:providerpractice/counter.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int count = 0;
  Timer? timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      var pro = Provider.of<Counter>(context, listen: false);
      pro.addCounter();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build" + count.toString());
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Provider State Management"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Consumer<Counter>(builder: ((context, value, child) {
              return Text(
                value.counter.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
              );
            }))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Getting This error when using provider]

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you can't use "context" in the initState method, rather move it out of there put it in a didChangeDependancy method.

I am sure someone can elaborate more on this, but the widget has no context until after the initState.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you're getting is a result of the fact that you do not have any logic to dispose of your active work. Try implementing something in `onDispose()`.

You could also elaborate more on the error you're getting. There is no mention of the error type or statement in your question.

Comment: For the last bit, if you believe a question doesn't contain sufficient detail to offer a reliable answer, please consider flagging it as requiring more detail.

Comment: Turns out I need more rep points to do some things

Comment: You should have gained that privilege at 15 reputation ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)). Though that may have been earned after this answer was posted.

Comment: I just got the extra points on another answer I provided.